# Grouping data and find sum

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, mean

I am working with the following data and I want to group  and find the mean of the grouped data according to time range i.e from 0 to 4, 0 to 4, 0 to 3, 0 to 6, 0 to 3 and 0 to 4 which means I'll remain with 6 rows with the average of the current in each row. And, I tried to do it with the following codes.

```
import pandas as pd
Time = [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3, 0,1,2,3,4] # in minutes
Current  = [0,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6,0,1,1,2,-1,2,2,3,4,5,5,0,-1,3,4,0,1,1,2,4] # in Ampere
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time (Min)': Time,'Current (A)': Current})
print(df)

xx = df.groupby(['Time (Min)']).sum() 
print(xx)
```

But, I'm getting the following results

```
Time (Min)          Current (A)   
0                     0
1                     7
2                    13
3                    19
4                    19
5                     5
6                     5
```

Any idea of how to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Expected Output
[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like

```
df.groupby(df['Time (Min)'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())['Current (A)'].mean()
```

---

```
     Time (Min)
1    2.800000
2    3.200000
3    1.000000
4    2.857143
5    1.500000
6    1.600000
Name: Current (A), dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups for every occurrence of zero in the `Time` column and take the mean of those groups

```
df.groupby(df['Time (Min)'].eq(0).cumsum())['Current (A)'].mean()
```

Out:

```
Time (Min)
1    2.800000
2    3.200000
3    1.000000
4    2.857143
5    1.500000
6    1.600000
```

---

### How this works

Check which row is zero in `Time`

```
df['Time (Min)'].eq(0)
```

Out:

```
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
12    False
13    False
14     True
15    False
16    False
...
```

Accumulate add the `True` values to get distinct numbers for every range from 0 to n

```
df['Time (Min)'].eq(0).cumsum()
```

Out:

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    3
11    3
12    3
13    3
14    4
15    4
16    4
...
```

Now you can group by the groups you expected.